# ip command vs route command, what's the difference?

Tags: linux, ip, ipv6, linux-networking, route

I see both `ip` and `route` commands used for configuring the kernel routing tables. What's the difference? It seems to me that the `ip` command is preferred more. Is it so, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `ip` command and `iproute2` tools in general is the preferred way to do this now as the `net-tools` package is deprecated, the last release being 1.6.

Having said that it seems likely that net-tools will be around for a long time to come as it is so deeply entrenched in the sysadmin muscle memory.